# save method in CrudRepository(Spring Data Cassandra) can't save a null value in date type field?

Tags: java, spring, cassandra

I'm using the Spring Data Cassandra in my project, i need to save a date value in the Cassandra table, the column type is Date in DB, i can save the value in it, but i can't set it back to null. When i was calling the

> CrudRepository ->save(obj)

, the data in the field was not removed. I tried to set the date field in the bean to null, then call the save method, it not work.

I'm wondering how can i save the date value back to null?

Anyone please help.

Thanks.

---

The cassandra can support insert many times for the same record. So I just call the same method for both create and update. If i use the cassandra api, to create a BoundStatement, use the SQL "insert into xxxx(a,b) value(?,?);" i can insert the null value to the table successfully. But if i call the repository's save() method, the date value will be the same as before.

Comment: Can you please paste the code too? Are you using any annotations?

Comment: No other annotation, just a @Repository on the XXXRepo interface. The problem is if i use driver api it works, and if i use the SpringData Cassandra's repo, it not works.

Answer (score 0):

If date is primary key then you can't save . if date is not primary key then you can delete date column .

Comment: Yes, thank you Mahendra Singh. You are right, i can delete the column. Then i need at least 2 db call to perform this update, one is to update the not null date column, and one is to delete the null date column. Can i just use one call for this update? Just like one simple save or update.